# How did Leon Kowalski escape the Tyrell corporation after his Voigt-Kampff Test?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

In the original [*Blade Runner*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner), a blade runner named Holden administers the Voigt-Kampff test, which is designed to distinguish replicants from humans based on their emotional response to questions. The test subject, Leon Kowalski, shoots Holden on the second question.

**How did he escape the Tyrell Corporation after the shooting?**

It is a heavily fortified building. They probably have armed guards who would have shot at Leon without a moment's hesitation.

Is there anything from any source that provides more information on this scene?

Comment: Given the test area looked like some boring cube farm, I didn't assume they were at the ziggurat HQ.

Comment: Leon escaped from the Tyrell corporation and Luv walked right into a secure area of LAPD not once but twice in the 2049 movie. What lax security!

Comment: There's no mention of how Leon escapes/leaves specifically. I'd hazard a guess it is because he still has his pass and could walk out in the chaos? 

In the novel it is Polokov who gets Holden; but, even there, it doesn't say specifically how he escaped (although he was using a W.P.O. identification, which would carry more weight as identification when leaving the scene).

Comment: How did Leon smuggle a gun into Tyrell HQ?

Answer (score 1):

In the [original script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/blade-runner_shooting.html), Leon uses a (presumably silent) laser gun to kill Holden, thus not alerting anyone to the fact that he just shot him.

> **LEON:**  *My...*
>
> [Leon looks shocked, surprised.  But the needles in  the computer barely move.  Holden goes for the inside of his coat.  But big Leon is faster.  His laser burns a hole the size of a nickel through Holden's stomach.  Unlike a bullet, a laser causes no impact.  It goes through Holden's shoulder and comes out his back, clean as a whistle.  Like a rag doll he falls back into the seat.  Big slow Leon is already walking away, but he stops, turns, and with a little smile of satisfaction fires through the back of the seat.]
>
> [As Leon walks out of the room the Voight-Kampff begins to blink, faint but steady.]

In the film version, he has a gun, but there's no good reason to assume that the same doesn't really hold true. People probably heard a loud bang nearby, but wouldn't immediately suspect a janitor of having murdered someone. Additionally, Leon will have a pass or some way of moving through the building and there's no reason to assume that this pass would have stopped working the moment he pulled the trigger.

---

In the comic novelisation, we're just told that he departs the building.

[image]

Comment: That might explain the purple hue that I keep seeing when I rewatch the clip when he shoots the coffee cottle. Everytime, I was thinking: "that doesn't look like a bullet".